# Add Multiple IDs - Search Box

Tags: javascript, html, search

I have three ol created but while adding search its not working.. Can you please check what is the problem?

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ol id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
</ol>

<ol id="myUL2">
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
</ol>

<ol id="myUL3">
  <li><a href="#">Anim</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bitto</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ol>
```

The script which im using is below :

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ol = document.querySelectorAll("#myUL,#myUL2,#myUL3");
    li = ol.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this line to get all the list items from the ordered list.

`li = document.querySelectorAll("ol li");`

```js
console.clear();

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ol, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    li = document.querySelectorAll("ol li");

    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<ol id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#">Adele</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
</ol>

<ol id="myUL2">
  <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
</ol>

<ol id="myUL3">
  <li><a href="#">Anim</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Bitto</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
</ol>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sifat Haque

Comment: How to hide a h4 above ol? I have similar lines on top of ever ol..

***<h4>Name List 3</h4>***

Comment: you can apply css to hide those.

Comment: Please create a new post with this new issue and provide proper code on that post.